# Checking if radio buttons are checked in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox

On my site, I have two checkboxes created in my ASP.NET MVC view like so:

```
Html.RadioButton("check", "true", "true" == (string) ViewData["someKey"], new { id = "check1"});
Html.RadioButton("check", "false", "false" == (string) ViewData["someKey"], new { id = "check2"});
```

I am positive that ViewData["someKey"] has the value "true" in it.

In my JS init function, I perform the following check:

```
alert($('#check1').is(':checked') + " " + $('#check2').is(':checked'));
```

In Firefox (and only Firefox), my alert dialog will show the following (it works as expected in every other browser):

```
Initial page load: true false
Normal refresh via Ctrl + R: false false
Refresh skipping cache via Ctrl + Shift + R: true false
```

I have tried many different methods of looking at the checkbox value, including `$('#check1').attr('checked')` without success.  If I examine the HTML in Firebug, I can see that the first radio button has the property `checked="checked"` in it.

Why is the checkbox value changing in FF when I refresh, and how can I mitigate this?  Since this seems to be a FF-only bug, how can I change my code to make it work?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery) seemed to ask something similar, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work in this case.

**Edit**: I should also point out that when the radio button is rendered after the refresh in FF, it's not actually being *displayed* as checked either, despite what the HTML is telling me.

**Edit2**: Adding raw HTML as per request

```
<input id="check1" type="radio" value="True" name="check" checked="checked"/>
<input id="check2" type="radio" value="False" name="check"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem isn't with *checking* whether or not the radio buttons are checked, but more that they buttons are actually unchecked even though the HTML code says otherwise.

I've posted a followup question to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574988/radio-buttons-being-reset-in-ff-on-cache-refresh) as an addendum to this topic.

**EDIT**: [This page](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-asmselect/issues/detail?id=5) has a good description of the problem and the solutions you can take to solve it.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify that it's actually due to a Firefox bug that appears when you add or remove input fields dynamically: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=539228

Answer (score 1):

Can we see the generated HTML? Are you really creating two radio buttons with both the same name *and* the same value?

Remember when you hit refresh, browsers try to preserve the form field contents of the page before the refresh. This includes radio button state. If you have two indistinguishable radio buttons that would seem to be a good way to confuse a browser trying to re-establish the form state.

Comment: I've added the offending HTML.

Comment: Erm, just noticed that my original code wasn't indicative of the problem.  The radio buttons had the same name, but different values.

(Apologies!)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this in FF3.0/3.5 with the code given. There aren't any other elements with id or name check1 are there? Does it make a difference if you skip jQuery and ask `document.getElementById('check1').checked`?

Comment: No, it makes no difference no matter how I check it.  The weird part is that the radio buttons are being rendered **unchecked** upon a normal refresh (so I think the JS is actually correct -- the button is "unchecked" even though there is nothing else with the same ID), yet on a cache-skip refresh everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your script could be running before the page is fully loaded. Where did you put the Javascript code? If you haven't already, try moving the code to the end of the `<body>` block.

Comment: I gave this a shot, and it didn't seem to help the issue.  This problem doesn't seem to appear in any other browser (not even IE!), so I'm a bit confused as to why Firefox would do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago and the issue was that I was doing the "check" before the item was fully loaded or rendered, it was a DropDownList that I rendered with jQuery.

My case was very specific, but I had to rework the code to take this into account...

Answer (score 0):

I used this to force firefox to reset the radiobuttons checked upon refresh.

```
$(function(){ $('input[name="radiobuttongroup"]')[0].checked = true; });
```

where [0] is the index of the radiobutton in the specific group ( [0] = first radio button, [1] = second radio button, ..)

Answer (score 0):

We've had a similar bug in firefox when using jquery to change the selection. Even though the code changed correctly according to firebug none of the radio buttons was selected. The solution we found is to remove the radio buttons from the DOM and just put them back.

```
var allradiobuttons = $('...');
allradiobuttons.click(function() {
  var radiobutton = $(this);
  allradiobuttons.removeAttr("checked");

  radiobutton.attr("checked", "checked");
  var parent = radiobutton.parent();
  parent.html(parent.html()); // This is a weird fix
}
```